# Android Studio 0.9.1 Gradle build failed. Error:Cause: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Android Studio is giving me this error:`Gradle project sync failed. Basic Functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.`

Here is error message:
     `Error:Cause: peer not authenticated
           Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed`
 [I tried this the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734738/android-studio-gradle-build-failed-errorcause-peer-not-authenticated), however I gave me the same issue.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file for your app.

Comment: I upgraded to the Android Studio 1.0 RC 2 and gradle is working fine now. (Had to scrap the project, but oh well)