# Android Studio / Intellij, Gradle Error:Cause: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, android, ssl, intellij-idea, gradle

Having a fight with IntelliJ at the moment. 
The darn thing won't download Gradle 2.1

I have an Android project hosted on GitHub, which I have cloned to my laptop.
I have got working SSL certificates, I know this as I can download SDK software from google using SSL, and I can also download Gradle 1.12.
The message I have received from IntelliJ is the rather infamous `Error:Cause: peer not authenticated` error.

From the terminal running IntelliJ I get this:

```
    * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'SomeAndroidProject'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.0.
     Required by:
         :SomeAndroidProject:unspecified
      > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.13.0/gradle-0.13.0.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated
```

I have search far and wide across the internet, with no avail. Please help me wise SO guru's!

Comment: Oh, and it's the same with http address - I have only just tried https recently. I'm not going to lie - I haven't a clue how to use or configure gradle. docs give you a 400 page pdf - it's almost larger then the Java language specification itself! ^_^

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Change your repositories syntax in build.gradle as following. See following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675814/gradle-could-not-head-https-pom-peer-not-authenticated).

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your java version may be different in your desktop computer. See linked question.

Comment: This should be changed in project gradle file if you updating the gradle version not in the app folder

Answer (score 5):

I've fixed this issue by adding the following to my build.gradle:

```
repositories { 
        maven { 
            url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'; 
        } 
}
```

Once done, try syncing and rebuilding your project.
Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

you should import the certificate:

First of all download the certificate (.cer) from [this url](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/steffenschaefer/gwt-gradle-plugin/maven-repo/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin/0.3/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.3.pom), Help is [here](http://docs.bvstools.com/home/ssl-documentation/exporting-certificate-authorities-cas-from-a-website)

Copy it to the path `JDK_HOME/jre/lib/security`

Then with command prompt targeted to above location, run the following command:

```
keytool -import -alias git -file <cert_file_name_you_exported.cer> -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Type yes if it prompts for approval, after that open the desired IDEA and have fun :)

If this doesn't help, try importing the certificate to `JRE/lib/security/cacerts`, It's totally depend on the build path of the IDEA you are using

Comment: After struggling for couple of hours this was the onlu solution that works. Just a note: the name of the certificate in my case was "ESETSSLFilterCA.crt" - extension crt and not cer

Answer (score 2):

yeah I experienced exactly same situation
It is not easy, but now I'm clear

I changed the build.gradle located in project forlder, not in app folder

I changed as below

```
repositories {
    jcenter 
    { 
        url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' 
    } 
}
```

instead of

```
repositories {
    jacenter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this issue by adding the following to me build.gradle:

```
repositories{
   maven {    
       url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2';
         }
 }
```

Once done, try syncing and rebuilding your project.
Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When I updated to Android Studio 1.0 I found that I need to update to use 1.0.0 version of gradle.

Inside of the build.gradle file I had

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0-rc2'
```

I changed it to remove the "-rc2"

```
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

"Error:Cause: peer not authenticated."

As this occurs I using Ubuntu: When I changed version on android studio 2.0 9 preview beta 1.

How do I fix my gradle.

Simply created a new project in android studio and then went in and saw build.grandle version gradle in my case:

```
 dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta1'
     }
```

and replace in my project.

I hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Like BzH :

This is a Java SSL connection error I solved on Github [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6362#issuecomment-189852511).

You need to add the appropriate SSL certificate to the java keystore for java accept the connection.

Work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

in case when there are some problems with internet 
try to add a line

```
54.231.14.232 s3.amazonaws.com
```

to your `/etc/hosts (..\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)`