# Gradle build failing for Google Cloud Module

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin

I created a project with Google cloud Module. While building I was peer not authenticated error.

Next I replaced `jcenter` with `mavenCentral()` and was able to download and add `appengine-sdk`, `appengine-endpoints,appengine-endpoints-dep`.

After doing all this build is failling with the following error message.

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0
```

Stuck at this point. Please help on this issue

Thanks in advance

```
    buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
}
```

}

```
repositories {
mavenCentral();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
downloadSdk = true
appcfg {
    oauth2 = true
}
endpoints {
    getClientLibsOnBuild = true
    getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
}
```

}

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: *Next I replaced jcenter with mavenCentral()* why? jcenter is a superset of maven

Comment: while using jcenter() I was getting peer not authenticated error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Next I replaced jcenter with mavenCentral()

I don't know why you did that. Jcenter is a superset of mavenCentral which basically means it can do the same, and more.

The peer authentication error you name in the comments should be solved with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27207281/1843331) and then you can proceed normally.

Below is a minimal working setup in order to sync `google-api-client-android:1.19.0`:

**Project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**App build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0'
}
```

You need not have the same values in the `android{ }` part, but the rest is important.

Also note there is a newer version of google-api-client-android, namely 1.20.0

Comment: Thanks for the help. Solution: in Project build.gradle file replaced jcenter with mavenCentral.