# Android studio download resource not compile in dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've always programed Android with Eclipse and decided to start migrating to Android Studio.

In my project, I added some libraries...

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /* For Google Play Services */
    //Firebase
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.2.2'
}
```

I got error in build gradle.
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

```
> Could not download firebase-client-jvm.jar (com.firebase:firebase-client-jvm:2.3.0)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/firebase/firebase-client-jvm/2.3.0/firebase-client-jvm-2.3.0.jar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/firebase/firebase-client-jvm/2.3.0/firebase-client-jvm-2.3.0.jar'.
         > peer not authenticated
```

I released that: I didn't add **firebase-client-jvm-2.3.0** library to complie. But I got this error.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734738/android-studio-gradle-build-failed-errorcause-peer-not-authenticated) but issue is not resolve.

Could you explain and help me resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [Gradle Could not HEAD https://..pom > peer not authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675814/gradle-could-not-head-https-pom-peer-not-authenticated) - you should use HTTP instead of HTTPS in repo URL:

```
repositories {
    jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
```