# peer not authenticated: Error while building app in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, crashlytics, fabric.io

I have been trying to build the application which uses crashlytics from fabric.io. 
But build gets failed with bellow mentioned error.

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
     Required by:
         TestProject18July2016:app:unspecified
      > Could not resolve io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+.
         > Failed to list versions for io.fabric.tools:gradle.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.367 secs
```

My internet is behind proxy server. I have enabled both HTTP & HTTPS settings in gradle.properties file.

```
## Project-wide Gradle settings.
#
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
#
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
#
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
#Mon Jul 18 11:14:57 IST 2016
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=<PASSWORD>
systemProp.https.proxyUser=<USERID>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<PORT>
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<PROXY_SERVER_ADDRESS>
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=<PASSWORD>
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<PROXY_SERVER_ADDRESS>
systemProp.http.proxyUser=<USERID>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<PORT>
```

My build.gradle file is bellow:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app.gradle file is bellow:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "testfirebase.kishor.testproject18july2016"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  /*  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'*/
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Currently I am using Android Studio Version 1.5.1(Tried 2.1 also, but no luck.)
I have searched google a lot, but not able to find exact solution.

Kindly Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long efforts I have identified a workaround for it.

Actually the problemetic maven url : https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

was redirecting to bellow url  : 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

Somehow in Android studio, this redirection was failing. So in app `build.gradle` file, I replaced the the maven url. 
from

```
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
```

to

```
 maven { url 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/fabric-artifacts/public' }
```

Which solved my problem.

Comment: this worked for me. any chance you got to get it working without said change?

Comment: @RahulTiwari, Nope. I could not find any other solution for this.